# How can I customize UI of angular material navbar so that it always show icons at least?

Tags: angular, angular-material, navigation

I am going to customize UI design of the angular material navbar.

It is hidden when toggling.
I'd like to always show only icons and whenever toggle let it expand to show the titles like in other bootstrap templates.
Is there a way I can do that?

I think this is dummy but I added ngIf to show or hide label and tried to fix that with CSS but not sure how I can do that keeping the animation and in a better way.

Or I can't keep the material nav?

```
      <li *ngFor="let item of thirdMenuLinks">
        <button class="light"
          type="button"
          mat-button">
          <i class="material-icons">{{item.icon}}</i>
          <span *ngIf="showFiller>{{item.name}}</span>
        </button>
      </li>
```

[Image for Expected nav after toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPt0F.png)

[Image for Expected nav before toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2px5.png)

Comment: This is still a feature request https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1728

Comment: Note from that discussion there are some possible workarounds -- check out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html